# activex can't create object by vbs but can by classic asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, com, activex, windows-server-2008-r2

On my Windows Server 2008 R2 I installed a COM object and can create it from a classic ASP page.

When I call it from a vbscript file, I get the "can't create" message.

I have tried starting Powershell as administrator and using that to run the script. No luck.

I have tried giving the "everyone" user full control over the COM DLL. No luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that makes sense to me is that the COM object is the same bit-ness as the class ASP and a different bit-ness than the script engine.  I do not know, but I would guess that the classic ASP is 32-bit and your COM object is 32-bit.

To check if it is bit-ness (mismatch between 32 and 64 bit), go to the command line and type

```
cscript myscript.vbs
```

where myscript.vbs is the name/path of your vbscript file.  Then, from the command line, type

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript myscript.vbs
```

The version of `cscript` (or `wscript`) that runs from a standard command prompt is 64-bit.  The one that runs from the `\Windows\SysWOW64` directory is the 32-bit version.

You can also look at your object's registration.
You can look at the ProgID in the registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and find the `CLSID`.

The 64-bit hive for the object will be under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\Your-prog-id`.

The 32-bit hive for the object will be under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\Your-prog-id`.